# How to conditionally add the nofollow tag in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, nofollow

I have a link and would like to add the `rel=nofollow` only on specific link.

It is possible to do that with Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TLDR

`[rel]="i ? 'nofollow' : null`

### Why

Basically, When using the `null` value, the tag will just be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like this

```html
<a [attr.rel]="addNofollowAttribute ? 'nofollow' : null" href="https://example.com">Your Link</a>
```

In this example, `[attr.rel]` binds the `rel` attribute to the value `'nofollow'` when `addNofollowAttribute` is `true`, and it binds it to `null` (which effectively removes the `rel` attribute) when `addNofollowAttribute` is `false`.

Comment: Did you try your code ?

Actually rel isn't working with `[attr.rel]`, or am I wrong? Because it made me wondered at the beginning, this was then the reason why I've opened a stackoverflow Q&A and answered it myself :)